# Custom PowerShell Snapin: custom format doesn't work

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, pssnapin

I used [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163293.aspx) to write my first own Powershell Cmdlet and Snapin. And it works fine.

But I return a set of objects from my own data class, which has four properties and I want Powershell to display just one of these properties by default. So I used [this part of the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163293.aspx#S14) to create this format file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <ViewDefinitions>
        <View>
            <Name>RemoteFile</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <TypeName>MyFullNamespace.RemoteFileData</TypeName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                    <TableColumnHeader />
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Filename</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                        </TableColumnItems>
                    </TableRowEntry>
                </TableRowEntries>
            </TableControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

and link it in the Snapin:

```
    public override string[] Formats
    {
        get { return new string[] { "MyFormatFilename.ps1xml" }; }
    }
```

But when I install the Snapin with installutil, use Add-PSSnapin and call my Cmdlet, all Properties of the objects are displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just in case: do you know that snap-ins are kind of obsolete approach and preferred (and simpler, really) way is modules? I created a lot of modules with any kind of custom formatting added and never had an issue. N.B. This is not an answer to your question in any way but maybe you still want to try modules, not snap-ins.

Comment: @Roman no, I didn't know that. Do you have a link to a tutorial for modules? Why are snapins obsolete? Microsoft used one for its SharePoint 2010 Cmdlets ... sounds not so ancient to me ...

Comment: Snap-ins approach is not that ancient or obsolete but they just invented a better way – modules. Why better? Just because they are simpler to develop, configure and deploy (xcopy installation). Here is the MSDN link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878310(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I will have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: @hinek: snapins are the only choice for powershell v1; the sp2010 folks wanted v1 compatibility. modules are for powershell v2 only (default on windows 7, 2008r2 - but v2 can be installed on xp/vista/2003 also)

Comment: @Roman and @x0n: Thanks for the informations about modules, was an interesting read, sadly didn't change my original problem. :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks correct except that I'm not sure how it behaves with no column header label defined.  Try adding this node instead of your empty one:

```
<TableColumnHeader>
  <Label>FileName</Label>
</TableColumnHeader>
```

Also make sure the file `MyFormatFilename.ps1xml` is in the same dir with the snapin when it is being loaded via Add-PSSnapin. Also, probably a duh, but double check for typos in the type name specified in the `<TypeName>` element.

Update: I tried your XML as listed above and it works for me.  I copied it into Notepad2 and saved it to C:\temp\test.ps1xml then executed:

```
1# $obj = new-object psobject
2# $obj.psobject.TypeNames.Insert(0, 'MyFullNamespace.RemoteFileData')
3# Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Filename `
              -Value 'some-remotefile.txt'
4# Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Dummy `
              -Value 'dummy prop'
5# $obj.psobject.TypeNames
MyFullNamespace.RemoteFileData
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Object
6# $obj

Filename                                                    Dummy
--------                                                    -----
some-remotefile.txt                                         dummy prop


7# Update-FormatData C:\temp\test.ps1xml
8# $obj

Filename
--------
some-remotefile.txt
```

I would double check the full typename `instance.GetType().FullName` and also double check the contents of the format file.  Make sure it is in the same dir that you registered the snapin from.

Comment: I tried it with and without <Label> but it didn't change the outcome ... also checked <TypeName> and ps1xml in the Snapin dir. The TypeName is the type of the displayed data, not the type of the cmdlet, right?

Comment: Hi Keith, the TypeName is the type of the displayed data, right? So if I return the data in my cmdlet by executing WriteObject(new RemoteFileData(...)); the TypeName must be the namespace and name of RemoteFileData, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  After your snapin is loaded, do a `Get-FormatData -TypeName <full type name>` on your type and see if it is making it into the format data.  Also, run the output of your cmdlet through `Get-Member` and double-check the full typename.

Comment: Funny thing: when I tried your suggestions (thanks by the way), I found out, that I get the correctly formatted output, when I call just my cmdlet. But if I call "Get-Help My-Cmdlet" first and then My-Cmdlet it still returns the output without following my view ... crazy!?

Comment: Yeah that is pretty crazy. If you call `Get-Help My-Cmdlet` first and then `Get-FormatData -Type <full type name>` does your format data still show up?